# For loop with Datagridview1.SelectedRows().cells().value has 'Index was out of range.' [vb.net]

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, vb.net-2010

My values in Datagridview is

```
|   warranty  |
---------------
|    0001     |
|    0002     |
|    0003     |
|    0004     |
```

values from code :

```
Private Sub UpdateGrid()

    Dim str As String = "select Warranty from TBwarranty"

    ds = New DataSet
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter(str, connection)
    da.Fill(ds, "a")

    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("a")

End Sub
```

Please can someone really tell me what's wrong with this code that I'm having this error:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index'

At first I coding:

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Dim c As Integer = DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count() - 1 

    For i As Integer = 0 To c

        Dim deleteQuery As String = "DELETE from TBwarranty WHERE warranty='" & DataGridView1.SelectedRows(i).Cells(0).Value & "'"

        Try
            T.ExecuteQuery(deleteQuery, connection) 'This my public sub in other class [ command.ExecuteNonQuery() ]
            UpdateGrid()
        Catch ex As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            MessageBox.Show("Fail inserted.")
        End Try

    Next

End Sub
```

Then there was a problem error above.

Then I tried coding:

```
    Dim c As Integer = DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count() - 1 

    For i As Integer = 0 To c

        Dim deleteQuery As String = "DELETE from TBwarranty WHERE warranty='" & DataGridView1.SelectedRows(i).Cells(0).Value & "'"
        Console.WriteLine(deleteQuery)

    Next
```

It's don't have any error and out put in console is true value.

I don't understand why is this? What wrong? and How do I?  Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: You changed the rows collection by deleting row during iteration, which results in the initial selected indices become invalid or out of range. Many ways to do this. One of them, save the selected waranty values into a list. Then only you delete from the database based on the warranty values in the list.

Comment: @ajakblackgoat I get it! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From the advice of comment. Now I can solve the error.

```
Dim c As Integer = DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count() - 1 

    For i As Integer = 0 To c
        Dim deleteQuery As String = "DELETE from TBwarranty WHERE warranty='" & DataGridView1.SelectedRows(i).Cells(0).Value & "'"

        Console.WriteLine(deleteQuery)

        Try
            T.ExecuteQuery(deleteQuery, connection) 
        Catch ex As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            MessageBox.Show("Failed inserted.")
        End Try
    Next

    UpdateGrid()
```